# Driver.getConnection hangs using SQLServer driver and Java 1.6.0_29

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I didn't know where to write something about this and decided to do it here.

After loooong time debugging my program I could find out that calling Driver.getConnection(string, string, string) hangs the calling thread. Why(?), I really don't know, but I could find out that this happens with java 1.6.0_29 and not with java 1.6.0_26.

Full enviroment:

- OS: Tested on both redhat 6.1 and Windows 2008
- Driver: MS SQL Server JDBC Driver version 3.0.1301.101
- Java Versions: 1.6.0_26 and 1.6.0_29

As I previously told it works with 1.6.0_26.

Is there anyone that has any idea what's possibly causing this? Maybe some developer? :p

Best regards,

Rui

Comment: Same problem here.  Windows 7 x64, JDK 1.6.0_29, SQL Express 2008 R2 (10.50.1790), using sqljdbc4.jar, and it hangs on getConnection.  Whereas it worked/works just fine with 1.6.0_24 for me (I have not tried other versions yet, just these two.)

Comment: Reproduced with SQL server 2008R2. SQL 2005 & 2008 work normally.

Comment: Problem is solved in 1.6.0.30

Comment: Yes, had the same problem with 1.6.0_29 and I verified the fix in 1.6.0_33.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same behaviour:

I use both Oracle XE and MS SQL Server Express on my Windows 7 64bit PC - I upgraded to java 1.6.0_29 from 1.6.0_27 (the x64 version) and was surprised to see that the same programs where able to connect to Oracle XE but not to MS SQL Server...

I traced down the problem to `javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection()` where it was hanging forever - because this is just an interface, the jdbc drivers raised my suspicion...

I'm using the MS SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0.1301.202 and I even updated to SQL Server CTP (the "community technical preview") 4.0.1722.1 because my suspicion was that it has to do something with the jdbc driver - but no success: still hanging!

My workaround was to downgrade to 1.6.0_27 and -- bang: everything was fine again!

best regards
Erich

Comment: I added as well a Bug Report on the Java Bug Database.
But since Oracle took over, this does hardly work. I did not hear anything back from Oracle nor can I find other bugs at the moment...

Comment: So, how exactly do you downgrade java to 1.6.0_xx on OSX Lion?

Answer (score 7):

Reproduced:
Problem occurs with combination of

- SQL driver 2.0
- SQL driver 3.0
- SQL driver 4.0 CTP 3
- jTDS SQL Driver 1.2.5
- SQL server 2008R2
- Java 1.6.0_29

Change either SQL server version (tested on 2005 & 2008) or Java version (1.6.0_27, 1.7.0_1), and the problem doesn't occur anymore.

Client / Server OS: Windows 2008R2

Added to the [Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7105007) and is being worked on by Oracle.

Crossposted on [Microsoft MSDN Data Access Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/97dce8fd-6487-4bca-80b0-492167db3e0d) (accepted answer: upgrade to java 7) and [Oracle Java JDBC Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301826&tstart=0) (information that is added here, is also added to the Java Bug Database).

Answer (score 4):

See the solution here
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9954398&tstart=0
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/97dce8fd-6487-4bca-80b0-492167db3e0d

"Apparently, this is related to SSL use and can be mitigated by replacing the jsse.jar in the jre/lib with that from an earlier version, for instance out of the 1.6.0_27 release. I've been confused by 1.6.0_29 working with MS JDBC and older SQL Server '05 setups which are not doing secure connections. All the newer servers (SQL Server '08 R2) fail as they require SSL and Java 1.6.0_29 does not work using jTDS or MS JDBC in this case."

Answer (score 3):

As an FYI, it appears that there's a new step build #30 in the 1.6 family which fixes the issue:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7103725

Answer (score 1):

I have the same hang problem, and only with java 1.6.0_29. I noticed that if I upgrade to 7.1 the problem goes away

Answer (score 1):

I am so happy that I have found this forum. I had the same problem on upgrade (I actually upgraded from 1.6.0_22 to 1.7.1, then downgraded to 1.6.0_29, when the problem has occurred.

One more thing I have noticed : if I use 1.6.0_29 jre, it fails, but if I use 1.6.0_29 jdk, it works... I spent about a day trying to figure why eclipse (which was using the jre) was failing while myEclipse (which was using the jdk) was working....

How can a bug be introduced to such a late release ? (I am in the process of making a java production version recommendation).

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here (SQLJDBC4, MsSQL 2008 R2, JDK1.6.0.29), but after updating to [1.6.0.30](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u30-download-1377139.html) problem was solved...

So it should be a critical bug in the DriverManager of 1.6.0.29

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to 1.6.0_30 also worked for me. Microsoft has released [a statement](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aMB49T9fF3xAJ%3ablogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/19/patch-available-for-sql-server-and-java-6-update-30.aspx&cd=7&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it) announcing the fix in 2012 Q1. It looks like it's a Java vulnerability (BEAST).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue where jBoss would hang on driver.getConnection().  However, I was using jBoss EAP 5.1, java 1.6.0_37x64, Sql Server 2005, and **jtds1.2.5** as my jdbc driver.

The work around I had to use was a jvm setting at startup: -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false and that resolved it.

I don't consider this a fix, but rather a work-around at this point.

I did find a bug: [7105007 : Microsoft & jTDS JDBC driver broken after update to 1.6.0_29](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7105007) that was very similar, but had a different cause.  What was interesting was that it showed up on both the MS drivers and jtds drivers.