# SQLCMD not working when run using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

This is an extremely strange situation, but I just cannot point out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm executing a big bunch of SQL scripts (table creation scripts, mostly). They are executed through Java, using `sqlcmd`. Here's the `sqlcmd` command I use.

```
sqlcmd -m 11 -S SERVER -d DB -U USER -P PASS -r0 -i "SCRIPT.sql" 2> "ERRORS.log" 1> NULL
```

*Note:* I use the `-r0` and redirects to make sure only errors go into the log file. I chuck out all STDOUTs.

Now I execute this command in Java, using `getRuntime.exec()`, like this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
strCmd = "cmd /c sqlcmd -m 11 -S SERVER -d DB -U USER -P PASS -r0 -i \"SCRIPT.sql\" 2> \"ERRORS.log\" 1> NULL"
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strCmd);
proc.waitFor();
```

*Note:* I use `cmd /c`, so that the command runs in its own shell and exits gracefully. Also, this helps in immediately reading the error log to look for errors.

**The Problem!**

This command works perfectly when run by hand on the command prompt (i.e. the tables are getting created as intended).  However, when executed through Java as shown, the scripts are run, and and there are no errors, no exceptions, nothing in the logs. ***But***, when checking in SSMS, the tables aren't there!

Where do I even begin debugging this issue?

**UPDATE: I'M A MORON**

The return value from the `getRuntime().exec` method is 1. It should be 0, which denotes normal execution.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

**UPDATE 2**

I've looked at the process' ErrorStream, and this is what it has.

> Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file 2>
>   (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
>   incorrect).

Looks like the path I'm passing is wrong. The error log goes into my profile directory, which is `C:\Documents and Settings\my_username`. Do the spaces in the path matter? I'm anyways double-quoting them!

Comment: Have you tried reading the output streams from the process?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Okay so I tried getting the ErrorStream, and it shows the error "Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file 2> (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: Do you have to redirect the streams? It should be the job of cmd to handle parsing of those. However, can you make it work if you skip the redirections completely and handle the stream form Java?

Comment: I do not want to do anything with the streams using Java. So I decided to let SQLCMD handle it. Now that this issue cropped up, I tapped into the ErrorStream to take a look at it. Also, take a look at my second update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the exec method with an string array as parameter:

```
 java.lang.Runtime.exec(String[] cmdArray)
```

The JavaDoc for this method says:

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.

So, the first item in the array is the command and all of your arguments are appended to the array, e. g.,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "sqlcmd ... "});
```

After looking at your comment and the implementation of `exec(String)` it seems to be, that the exec method recognizes the pipe operator `>` as an argument to `cmd`, because `exec(String)` splits the command string to an array using whitespaces as seperators.

Comment: Wow, this is exciting to learn so many things about Runtime! So I tried passing the entire command as a single-element array, like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {strCmd});`. Now the ErrorStream is empty, but the tables are still not getting created!

Comment: Did you tried to pass an array with three elements?

0. The command `cmd`
1. First argument to `cmd`: `/c`
2. Second argument to `cmd`: "sqlcmd -m ..."

Comment: Okay so I tried that. I'm getting the error "Access is denied." in the ErrorStream. Could `sqlcmd` be throwing this error?

Comment: Hm, try only the sqlcmd part and ignore for now the log files. It seems like sqlcmd returns error messages with the prefix "sqlcmd:".

Comment: THAT WORKS! I passed `sqlcmd -m 11 -S SERVER -d DB -U USER -P PASS -i "SCRIPT.sql"` and it works! But logging is extremely essentially for my purpose =[

Comment: Ok, one step succeded. I ha a look through the documentation of cmd (`cmd /?`). There is one sentence od interest: "Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator '&&'
are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes." So maybe the pipe operator `>` needs to be quoted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5660/discussion-between-gpx-and-h-man2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have privs to post comments - which is what this is - but what if you try putting in a bogus user id for the DB? Does that cause a different execution path? Will that give you a Java error? Or an Auth error in your DB? Also, def tweak the user, not the password and learn from my experience that if you tweak the password that's a great way to get an account locked out!

The other thing - and this may be a shot in the dark - but what are the JRE and driver you're using? I believe there's a known issue with JRE 1.6.0.29 and the sqljdbc4 JAR. I have more details on this, but I'll have to post the link once I get to work.

Edit:

I know it's been established that the JRE/sqljdbc combo isn't your issue, but if folks search and find this, here is the link I spoke of above:

[Driver.getConnection hangs using SQLServer driver and Java 1.6.0_29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29)

Comment: Matt, I'm using JRE 1.6.0.03 and the sqljdbc4 JAR. Also do check my second update!

Answer (score 0):

First enable log/view commands output (since exec() returns 1), which would point out possible cause of the issue.
Use proc.getInputStream() and print the contents to a file or console.