# Trouble connecting tomcat to MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am trying to connect my tomcat servers to a MS SQL 2008 R2 server.  Network connectivity is not the issue here.

I can successfully connect in a simple java app, but when I try to connect via tomcat7 (tried on my Windows 7 workstation as well as my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I am able to run the example servlets on both tomcat servers.

My code:

```
 public class DBConnector{`
 private java.sql.Connection  con = null;`
 private final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://my.domain.com:";`
```

//PORT NUMBER, CREDENTIALS, ETC.  These all work in standard java app.

```
public DBConnector(){}

private String getConnectionUrl(){
    return url+ portNumber +";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";
}

private java.sql.Connection getConnection(){
     try{
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
          con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(),userName,password);
          if(con!=null) System.out.println(getConnectionUrl());
     }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());

    }
     return con;
 }


    public void queryDB(){

    try{
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
         con= this.getConnection();
         if(con!=null){
             System.out.println("NotNull");

            java.sql.Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String query="Select * from CAFE";            
            java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
            System.out.println("made rs");
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Established what it is");
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Getting MetaData");`
 //Omitted the rest.
```

It stops responding in tomcat at: rs = statement.executeQuery(query); because on the console, I never see "Established what it is".

I am using the correct mssql driver version for Java 6.

I am very new to this so quite likely made an obvious mistake here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by stops responding? Does it sit there forever or does it actually throw an exception? If it throws and exception, what actual exception does it throw?

Comment: It just sits there forever, does not thrown an exception.

Comment: I believe I am experiencing this bug (I am using the exact same environnment).

I will try updating to 1.6-30 from 1.6-29.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Downgraded to:

## java -version

java version "1.6.0_24"

Working properly now.
Those who came here via search engine; refer to this:
[Driver.getConnection hangs using SQLServer driver and Java 1.6.0_29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29)