# Tomcat dataSource getConnection hang

Tags: tomcat, datasource

I have a problem when getting connection from Tomcat dataSource.

Here are the config files:

1. `server.xml`

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/mssql" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="30" maxActive="-1"
          maxIdle="-1" maxWait="10000"      username="xxx" password="xxx"       driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"      url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=XXX" />
```

1. `context.xml`

```xml
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/mssql" name="jdbc/mssql" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

From my application code:

```java
InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();

if(initContext == null) {
    String message = "There was no context in tomcat server..";
    throw new Exception(message);
}
DataSource datasourceLocal = null;
datasourceLocal = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/mssql");

if(datasourceLocal == null){
   String message = "Could not find the dataSource in tomcat server..";
   throw new Exception(message);
}
else {
    logger.info("ConnPool Success..");
}

Connection conn = datasourceLocal.getConnection();
```

I have 2 database servers (replace the IP with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in `server.xml`), its working fine with 1st one, but with the 2nd one, it just hangs on the getting Connection line (I put some trace before and after this line).

Comment: Did you check that port 1433 is reachable on both servers? You can test that using telnet.

Comment: lets say, my DB servers are S1 and S2. I also test my application in 2 servers S3 and S4. Situation is: App from S3 is working fine with DB in S1 and S2. App from S4 is only working with DB in S1 and not S2. So does that mean port 1433 is reachable for both S1 and S2?

Comment: i telnet from S3 and S4 to S1 and S2 through port 1433, all is ok

Comment: Are software versions identical on both servers (for JDK, JDBC driver and SQL Server)? Some combinations are reported to cause issues (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29)

Comment: uhm... different JDK (the working one is 1.6_27, the other is 1.7), JDBC driver is same but SQL server is different (the working one is 2012, the other is 2008R2). That might cause the problem, lets me make them identical on both servers and test again. Thanks!

Comment: So did it change anything?