# database connection to SQLServer hanging in socketRead0

Tags: java, sql-server, connection

I am trying to connect to my companies remote database SQLServer
I try this using the app, and squirelSQL and both hang and have to be killed.
When i use these parameters in SQLServer manangement studio (2008) i can connect.

I use exactly the same parameters as my work collegues and they connect straight away.

I am on windows, i have windows firewall turned off, but have the same remote security application as everyone else in the company.

Can anyone give me any straws to grab at, or any tools i can use to help analyse the problem further?

Answer (score 0):

I had java 1.6.29 which has a bug in it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Which bug was this? And which Java version fixed it? Does it occur wtih Java 7 as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29

Comment: this bug was just with that specific version of java