# JBoss/Spring not finding my JNDI / Hibernate config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, jndi

So I've set up a datasource in JBoss 6.2GA, called "**java:/jdbc/iconDS**"

Then I linked to it in persistence.xml, calling the entity manager factory "**java:jboss/persistence/icon**"

My web.xml loads a context reference to the persistent unit I set up, and also loads infrastructure.xml, which tries to look up my two JNDI names.

It says "Starting Persistence Unit Service 'iconRules.war#primary", but then "hibernate.properties not found", and regardless of whether I put in a hibernate.cfg.xml or not, it just hangs on :

```
HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider  
IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
```

Which indicates that it's just not working.

---

Edit:  solved.  Thanks Pascal for the help

Comment: Did you specify the connection url in the standalone.xml config of jboss? with the <connection-url> tag?

Comment: Hi Pascal, yes, it says "Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)" and "JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/iconDS]" in the startup, so I think it's configured correctly.

Comment: Hmm, when it fails though, it does say "Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/iconDS"

Comment: I've tried connecting with straight JDBC now, and it opens a connection, creates a statement from the connection, but then hangs on statement.execute(QueryString); indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with straight JDBC, and it still didn't work.  Eventually I found it was a bug with my Java 1.6 version!  ARGH

[Driver.getConnection hangs using SQLServer driver and Java 1.6.0_29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29)