# How to encrypt with SSL using JTDS driver

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, ssl

Our Java servlet connects to a `SQL server 2005 database` using the `sqljdbc.jar` driver in `Tomcat\lib directory` (Windows) and encrypts using SSL with the signed certificate in a keystore.  This works fine, but the database has now been `migrated to SQL Server 2008 R2` and the connection stopped working. I have successfully created a connection with the credentials using SQL Server Management Studio so the credentials and port number are fine etc.  I found using the JTDS driver (version 1.2.7) allowed a successful connection but I cannot get the encryption to work using SSL.  I added the JNDI attribute of `"ssl=require"` to the URL in the Tomcat JNDI but this still does not work.  I also tried `"ssl=authenticate"` but again no encryption.

What am I doing wrong?  Here is the JNDI entry although with certain information such as password and server nbame hidden.

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"   
factory="org.moss.jdj.dbcp.EncryptedDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" 
maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/edrms" password="*******" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://********:2369:\ngedm;databaseName=*******;ssl=require"  
username="*******" />
```

Comment: @vzamanillo thanks for correcting my question.  Do you have any guidance on resolving the problem?

Comment: What is your JVM runtime?

Comment: @vzamanillo my current JVM (jre and jdk) are 1.6.0.29 but since i posted my last comment I have found the following URL and I am currently upgrading to 1.6.0.30 and go back to using Microsofts JDBC4 to see if this resolves the issue.  See I tried Microsofts JDBC4 and it just keot timing out and hence I found JTDS worked but then I have the SSL problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841411/driver-getconnection-hangs-using-sqlserver-driver-and-java-1-6-0-29

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest JTDS driver? Did you applied the  Sql Server 2008 SP2 to your database server?

Comment: @vzamanillo Thanks for more feedback.  Yes I tried latest version of JTDS (version 1.3.1) but it wouldn't work with Java 1.6.0.29.  I aim to upgrade to Java 7 soon but a former colleague told me that there was a fundamental change to java in version 7 and I will have to investigate before upgrading toi version 7 of Java

Comment: @vzamanillo as for SQL Server 2008 upgrading I found the link below but unfortunately I have to get our infrastructure to do that one as we are not allowed. But it is in hand http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2653857

Comment: @AJF Could you please provide the part of EncryptedDataSourceFactory that creates the datasource?